# room hilt @Query doesn't return what i expected

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

Some queries return result right in RecipeDao.kt and side panel of the ide writes: Is implemented in com.example.mypackage.data.RecipeDao_Impl
but others doesn't return result
like this one for given date where is problem I extract app db and query it in other sqlite browser app and it executed succesfully

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QDhR.png)

```
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        dateNoDay?.get(pos)?.let { dateQuery -> //dateQuery here is yyyy/M
                            allRecipesByMonth = async {
                                recipeDao.getAllRecipesByMonth(
                                    "'$dateQuery/01'",
                                    "'$dateQuery/31'"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            allRecipesByMonth.await()
                            archiveRecipesAdapter = context?.let {
                                ArchiveRecipesAdapter(
                                    allFactorsByMonthOfYear.await(),
                                    it
                                )
                            }
                            archiveRecipesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
String as date can't be compared. I had two Solution for it. 
1.change it into long and work with it (recomended) 
2.change into 3 column of INTEGER (not recomended)  
I've done 2nd method for a reason and it worked.